# Microsoft Identity Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-identity

In my application I'm using Microsoft Identity Authorize to load an AspNet Core view and require the user credentials to access the page.

My problem is that IIS Express executing throug VS 2019, works just fine but when I publish it on IIS (both problem in self-dependent / self-contained) every time that I made a request to access the view it ask me to make the login over and over again.

My Startup.cs file:

```
namespace SistemaGestor.SOO.Mvc
{
    public class Startup
    {

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<SOOContext>(srv => SOOContextFactory.CreateInstance(Configuration));
        //Fernando Milanez 25/09/2019
        services.AddTransient<IEmbarcacaoInterface,EmbarcacaoRepositorio>();
        services.AddTransient<IBandeiraInterface, BandeiraRepositorio>();
        services.AddTransient<IAutenticacao, AutenticacaoRepositorio>();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Autenticacao/Login";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") },
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt-BR")
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication(); //Requisito para ativar a autenticao, então é sempre assim adiciono o middlewaree depois defino para usar
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
}
```

}

In my Controller, I've input the [Authorize] attribute:

```
namespace SistemaGestor.SOO.Mvc
{
    [Authorize]
    //logical code below
}
```

**I didn't post any error message because it does not show any error.**

Comment: Could you share which authentication you enabled in iis? did you enable windows authentication?

Comment: I was using the anonymous authentication but I changed it to Windows Authentication. Still not working

Comment: clear the browser history and cache and try again to access the site.